# How to remove the prefix printed out by tf.logging.info

Tags: python, tensorflow, logging, prefix, verbosity

Printing log lines in TensorFlow is done with functions in tf.logging like tf.logging.info, tf.logging.log, etc.

```
import tensorflow as tf;

tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO);
tf.logging.info(tf.__version__);
```

However, when printing on **Google Colab**, there's a real long prefix before the printed value:

```
I0903 10:16:46.097078 140433498875776 <ipython-input-9-a435f70e3dca>:22] 1.14.0
```

How to change tf.logging to omit that prefix? It's long and unnecessary. And even when running the code directly with `python3` in terminal, there's still a shorter prefix (the version is 1.12.0 in terminal):

```
INFO:tensorflow: 1.12.0
```

And I want to remove this short prefix too.

Comment: I can't seem to figure out this odd behaviour at first glance, can you tell me what is the result of `from tensorflow.python.util.tf_export import TENSORFLOW_API_NAME` (the constant's value - should be "tensorflow")? What's even more confusing is that there is no *INFO* printed out at all and the format is different. Could it be Jupyter (or whatever are you running it in) messing things up (but tensorflow should be guarding against that)? Is there a chance to receive a run-able example?

Comment: it's not jupyter, that long prefix is on Google Colab https://colab.research.google.com/

Comment: Well yes... And Google Colab commonly runs Python scripts in Jupyter notebooks (`ipynb` extension). And like I said I am incapable of reproducing your error unless you provide me a run-able example because your script prints `INFO:tensorflow:1.14.0` from within the Google Colab notebook just as expected.

Comment: @KacperFloriański i did face the problem before, but it's short by now: https://i.imgur.com/UpvCui3.png

Comment: @KacperFloriański anyway, is it possible to remove the prefix

Comment: Well like I said (again) I will not know unless you provide me with a run-able example capable of reproducing the error to let me figure this out, `ipython` bit in the line suggests this is Jupyter notebook doing something. You are doing this on Google Colab so you can simply share a link to a minimal example in it or share a sample here. But please don't ask me to rewrite your code from a screenshot.

Comment: @KacperFloriański yeah, me too, can't replicate the long prefix issue, but the prefix is still there; can we remove it? or it's fixed in tensorflow code?

Comment: Look man, I can't help you unless I am able to replicate the issue. You need to send me code which causes the problem for you or remove this question if it's fixed. Most people will be unable to help if you don't provide an example showing it doesn't work - just share the code which produces the prefix which you don't want to be there...

Comment: @KacperFloriański oh bro, i want to remove the whole prefix...... whatever short or long

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199421/discussion-between-kacper-florianski-and-datdinhquoc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer that it is impossible to remove the prefix by `tf.logging.*` functions. It is a done in the C/C++ level of the library and no way to remove it.

It is stated in there: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/12537

Comment: There's a way to do anything if you're brave enough